# limit : $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{b})^n=?$

Tags: limits, exponential-function, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

fine the limit :

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{b})^n=?$$

$a,b\in \mathbb{R}$

My Try :

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (1)+\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{b})^n=1+0=1$$

Because:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a}=1 $$

is it right ?

Comment: You need to see that $(x+y)^n$ not always is equal to $x^n+y^n$. You hace an indetermination of the form $1^ \infty$. Find the limit of the natural logarithm, and finally you need to apply exponential function.

Comment: @asd . $(\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{b}))^n=\lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{b})^n$

Comment: @Almot1960 You start by writing $\lim_n (1+f(n))^n = \lim_n 1+\lim_n (f(n)^n)$.As asd points out, this is not correct.

Comment: @Almot1960 Your tag is "without L'Hospital". Is this intended to be a problem without the Rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*No, this is not right.*

- Your first step:
  $$
  \lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{b})^n
  = \lim_{n\to \infty} 1
  + \lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{b})^n 
  $$
  is wrong. With the same argument, you would have $$\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+1)^n = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1^n + \lim_{n\to\infty} 1^n = 1+1 = 2$$ which is clearly false.
- Now, let us prove that the limit is $a^{1/b}$. *For everything to make sense to begin with, one must have $a,b>0$.* I will only use elementary arguments involving the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}e^x\mid_{x=0} = 1$ and $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(1+x)\mid_{x=0} = 1$.

  To begin with, let us put our quantity is the simpler to analyze exponential form: 
  $$
  (1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{b})^n
  = e^{n \ln\left(1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{b}\right)} 
  = \exp\left({n \ln\left(1+\frac{e^{\frac{\ln a}{n}}-1}{b}\right)}\right)
  $$
  so by continuity of $\exp$, it suffices to find the the limit of ${n \ln\left(1+\frac{e^{\frac{\ln a}{n}}-1}{b}\right)}$.

  Since $\frac{e^{\frac{\ln a}{n}}-1}{b}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{0}$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} = 1$, we can rewrite
  $$
  {n \ln\left(1+\frac{e^{\frac{\ln a}{n}}-1}{b}\right)}
  = n \cdot \frac{e^{\frac{\ln a}{n}}-1}{b} \cdot \underbrace{ \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{e^{\frac{\ln a}{n}}-1}{b}\right)}{\frac{e^{\frac{\ln a}{n}}-1}{b}}}_{\to_{n\to\infty} 1}
  $$
  and thus focus on the limit of $n \cdot \frac{e^{\frac{\ln a}{n}}-1}{b}$.
  Recalling that $1=\exp'(0) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}$ and that $\frac{\ln a}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$, we then can (!) write
  $$n \cdot \frac{e^{\frac{\ln a}{n}}-1}{b}
  =n\cdot\frac{\frac{\ln a}{n}}{b} \cdot \frac{e^{\frac{\ln a}{n}}-1}{\frac{\ln a}{n}}
  = \frac{\ln a}{b} \cdot \frac{e^{\frac{\ln a}{n}}-1}{\frac{\ln a}{n}}
  \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{\ln a}{b}\cdot 1.
  $$
  Putting it all together,
  $$
  (1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{b})^n
  = \exp\left({n \ln\left(1+\frac{e^{\frac{\ln a}{n}}-1}{b}\right)}\right)
  \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 
  \exp\left(\frac{\ln a}{b}\cdot 1\cdot 1\right)
  = e^{\frac{\ln a}{b}}
  $$
  giving that the limit is $e^{\frac{\ln a}{b}}=\boxed{a^{\frac{1}{b}}}$.

Comment: If you are familiar and comfortable with Taylor approximations, the whole second part can become a much more concise 3-line derivation.

Comment: I know your answer is right, but I made an error somewhere in my answer and I can't find it.  Could you look it over?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt You do get the same result, though -- don't you?

Comment: Check my last few steps and you'll see I sneaked the result through.  But I want to fix it :-/

Comment: I'll have a look asap! (Currently outside under the rain.)

Comment: :O May your future be not rained upon then

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Sorry to be daft, but your derivation looks fine to me. Which step is the one bugging you? (Showing the last limit is 1?)

Comment: Look really closely at the last limit.

Comment: Since $\sqrt[n]{a}\to 1$, this goes to $\frac{1}{1+\frac{1-1}{b}} = 1$ -- or am I misunderstanding what you say?

Comment: OH!  Wow, I'm stupid.  I was thinking that $\sqrt[n]a\to\infty$!  XD  Thank you for your helps

Comment: No worries! ${}{} $

Comment: You need $a>0, b\ne 0$ in this problem.

Comment: Yes, indeed... i wrote a,b > 0 for comvenience.

Answer (score 2):

Let $L$ be the limit.  Then,

$$\ln(L)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{\sqrt[n]a-1}b\right)}{1/n}\stackrel{L'H}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-1/n^2)\frac{\ln(a)}b\sqrt[n]a}{\left(1+\frac{\sqrt[n]a-1}b\right)(-1/n^2)}\\=\frac{\ln(a)}b\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\left(\frac1{\sqrt[n]a}+\frac{1-\frac1{\sqrt[n]a}}b\right)}\\=\frac{\ln(a)}b$$

Thus,

$$L=e^{\ln(a)/b}=\sqrt[b]a$$

Comment: I am not sure L'Hopital's rule is completely fine by the OP, given the tag.

Comment: @ClementC. Of course, but still, it's probably the recommended path for this type of problem.

Comment: You are assuming the limit exists at the outset. The above will be better written without all the limit notation until the end.